# postgres sql rows into a specifi xml format

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have the following data in my table

```
        name    exists
-------------------------
        Green   true
        Purple  false
```

I will have to convert these rows into the following xml

```
<Green>YES</Green><Purple>false</Purple>
```

I tried to use xmlforest but this returns something like this.

```
<name>Green</name><exists>true</exists>
<name>Purple</name><exists>false</exists>
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple output, it's probably easier to simply concatenate the values using `format()`

```
select format('<%s>%s</%s>', name, exists::text, name)
from the_table;
```

The only drawback is, that it won't properly escape names that aren't valid XML tags.

Answer (score 0):

If a simple string generation without any XML validation is ok for you, you should go with the solution of @a_horse_with_no_name.

If you want to create the XML elements using the XML functions of PostgreSQL, you need to generate a dynamic SQL with a formatted function:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=58b71b5e4982405213f5fa368e8c9502)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_xml(_name text, _val boolean) RETURNS xml
AS $$
DECLARE
    _result xml;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT xmlelement(name %I, %s)', _name, _val::text) INTO _result;

    RETURN _result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The problem is, that the element name cannot be set dynamically per record: [See here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRCUfHYF1LUCMZvdr_00B14G_YC5ZFJMEQpV-tS+p5srNA@mail.gmail.com)

Comment: Did this help? Otherwise, please tell us what to change. Please do not forget to upvote ALL answers which are helpful in ANY way (this honors the time and work, the repliers invested into your problem). If one answer solves your problem completely, click the check mark to accept it (to close the question)